# Expand kendo ui tree node using id

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i am creating kendo ui tree using binding to remote data http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html

i am new to kendo ui in this if i use bellow code to expand tree it works fine

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
// expand all nodes
treeview.expand(".k-item");
```

when i have tried it to using `id` it gives me undefined error

code is

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
// expand the node with id=3
treeview.expand(document.getElementById("3"));
//treeview.dataSource.view();
```

and this is my jquery code

```
var serviceRoot = "search/treej.php";
homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: serviceRoot,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            hasChildren: "child"
        }
    }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: false,    
    },
    dataSource: homogeneous,
    dataTextField: "value"
});

// my function to expand node using id it is called on my button click
function expand_me(){
    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    // expand the node with id=3
    treeview.expand(document.getElementById("3"));
}
```

i dont have much idea about this but expand is not possible for js fiddle (cause i am using database ) so i have created demo code for collapse http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/S3H6U/

can any buddy tell me where am i doing wrong??

Comment: can you share it in jsfiddle please?

Comment: @Parse i am unsing external file to get data

Comment: @Parse here is for collapse [http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/S3H6U/](http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/S3H6U/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsFiddle example doesn't have an element with an id of 3. `document.getElementById("3")` returns `null`.

If you know the uid from the Kendo DataSource for the item you want to collapse, you can use a jQuery selector to find the item with the matching `data-uid` attribute:

```
$("#treeview")
    .data("kendoTreeView")
    .collapse('.k-item[data-uid="a7e9f5fd-4c11-4e0f-bb16-ae335c70c73f"]');
```

Or if you mean the 3rd item in the tree:

```
$("#treeview")
    .data("kendoTreeView")
    .collapse($('.k-item').eq(2));
```